# how do I get a subset of strings from list 1 which are not present in list2?

Tags: c#, .net

I have two lists

```
list 1 = { "fred", "fox", "jumps", "rabbit"};
list2 ={"fred", "jumps"}
```

Now I need to get a list3 which contains elements of list1 which are not present in list2.
so list 3 should be

```
list3  = {"fox", "rabbit"};
```

I can do this manually by using loops but I was wondering if there is something like list3 = list1 - list2 or some other better way than using loops.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using .NET 3.5 or newer then you can use [**`Enumerable.Except`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx):

```
var result = list1.Except(list2);
```

If you want it as a list:

```
List<string> list3 = list1.Except(list2).ToList();
```

For older versions of .NET you could insert the strings from list1 as keys in a dictionary and then remove the strings from list2, then the keys that are left in dictionary is the result.

```
Dictionary<string, object> d = new Dictionary<string, object>();
foreach (string x in list1)
    d[x] = null;
foreach (string x in list2)
    d.Remove(x);
List<string> list3 = new List<string>(d.Keys);
```

Comment: @VNarasimhaM - you'll need to to have `using System.Linq;` to access this method.

Answer (score 1):

```
list1.Except(list2);
```